# Rails Oauth Devise Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, devise, omniauth

How could I make a user access his account in my app from different providers?
I have a project in Rails with devise and omniauth to allow access through google and facebook. How can I make it so that if a user has a different email address in the providers, they access the same account in my app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's really possible.

Unless they use the same email address for both Facebook and Google you can't know if the two are the same user or not.